# calculus problem, arithmetic

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Could someone help me with this please?
I am solving a limit problem, the problem is not understanding what to do but only this small step on the way.

I am missing how this can be, maybe I just have a blackout and I'll laugh later at how easy it was, but right now I need help and I am stuck.

So this is it, how can this be right?

$$ \frac{(x-1)(1+\sqrt{x})-2(x-1)}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{(x-1)((1+\sqrt{x})-2)}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$

Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Everything would have been OK if you **hadn't** put that extra $)$ in the numerator of the LHS

Answer (score 1):

That's just distributive property (in reverse). If your having trouble seeing it let $a=x-1$ then we have:

$$\frac{(x-1)(1+\sqrt{x})-2(x-1))}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}=\frac{a(1+\sqrt{x})-2a}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$

$$=\frac{a(1+\sqrt{x}-2)}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$

Comment: Thanx, I see it clearly now :)

Comment: No problem @user347483

Answer (score 0):

Take $(x-1)$ common from numerator and now it's the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the distributive property of the real numbers. Hence you get
$$ \frac{(x-1)(1+\sqrt{x})-2(x-1))}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2} = \frac{(x-1)((1+\sqrt{x})-2)}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.
This is a pretty standard result.

Answer (score 0):

The step was factoring out $x-1$ common to both terms in the numerator.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/654088)

Comment: @Qwerty the op is asking what the step involved in the double arrow is. The step is factoring out the $x-1$. What is the problem?